# Why is the scope wrong on MS Edge console at breakpoints?

Tags: microsoft-edge, console.log, javascript-debugger

I'm finding that in MS Edge when I use the `debugger;` statement or a breakpoint, the scope of `this` is always the global scope (e.g. the Window object) regardless of what the scope of `this` is where the code is actually breaking.

For example, the following code is inside a constructor (thus `this` is *not* the global object!):

```
this.myString = "hello";

// returns the current function scope [object Object]
console.log(this);

// returns "hello"
console.log(this.myString);

var fakeThis = this;


/* In this breakpoint, typing:
 * `this` returns [object Window]
 * `this.myString` returns undefined
 * `fakeThis` returns the correct function scope
 * `fakeThis.myString` returns "hello".
*/
debugger;
```

Is this a known bug with the MS Edge console or is there something specific that might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce the problem on my side (using Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0), it seems that everything works well on my side, the screenshot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDDxU.png), and the sample code as below:

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    // Constructor function for Person objects
    function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
      this.firstName = first;
      this.lastName = last;
      this.age = age;
        this.eyeColor = eye;

        this.myString = "hello";
        // returns the current function scope [object Object]
        console.log(this);
        // returns "hello"
        console.log(this.myString);
        var fakeThis = this;

        /* In this breakpoint, typing:
         * `this` returns [object Window]
         * `this.myString` returns undefined
         * `fakeThis` returns the correct function scope
         * `fakeThis.myString` returns "hello".
        */
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.myString);
        console.log(fakeThis);
        console.log(fakeThis.myString);
        debugger; 
    }

    // Create a Person object
    var myFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");

    // Display age
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "My father is " + myFather.age + ".";
</script>
```

please try to clear the cache and history, then re-test your code. Also, you could create a new page to test above code, check whether they are working on your side.